# Table view does not exist exception on Netbeans

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans-7, derby

I followed the instructions in [this tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/connect-db.html#testConnPoolDataSource). I am having problem with step: Testing the Connection Pool and Data Source. However, going through the steps over and over, I'm still getting the exception: Table/View 'CATEGORY' does not exist. Table exists when i checked under 'services'.

My JDBC connection URL that i specify is : jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/affablebean?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull

Netbeans 7.3.1
MySQL Server 5.6
Glassfish Server 4

Answer (score 5):

There is an error in the tutorial at Step 3 of "Creating a Resource Reference to the Data Source".

You can fix this by changing this line in your web.xml:

`<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>`

to

`<res-type>javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource</res-type>`

Should work now :)